# ViewPager child to swipe next the parent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager2 which I'm using with a RecyclerView Adapter. I'm binding the children of each viewpager item via the ViewHolder and everything is working okay.

I have a bunch of elements in this ViewPager item XML, some RadioButton components and a Button. I want this button to move it to the next item.

I know how to do that externally, assigning a sibling to the ViewPager2 and then setting a click-listener in the activity and then comparing currentItem of the ViewPager with the adapter's total item count.

I want the "Move to next" button inside the ViewPager as I want to change it based on the inputs supplied to the RadioButton components.

I'm currently stuck at failing getting the ViewPager item's button in the activity to set the click-listener. Is there any workaround to get the child element via the adapter itself?

Here's the activity_quiz.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.quiz.view.QuizActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/quiz_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/quiz_item" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The quiz_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/bigSpacing"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/question"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/choices">
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/choice_1"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/choice_2"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/choice_3"/>
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/choice_4"/>
    </RadioGroup>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/result_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next question" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The MyAdapter class (kotlin)

```
class MyAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
  override fun onCreateViewHolder(...) {
  ...
  }

  override fun getItemCount(): Int {
  ...
  }

  override fun onBindViewHolder(...) {
  ...
  }

  class MyViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
  fun bind(someData: SomeData) {
    
    itemView.question.text = somedata.question
    itemView.choice_1.text = somedata.choice_1
    itemView.choice_2.text = somedata.choice_2
    itemView.choice_3.text = somedata.choice_3
    itemView.choice_4.text = somedata.choice_4

    val answerKey = someData.answerKey
    var rightOrWrong = ""

    itemView.choices.setOnCheckedChangeListener {_, checkedID ->
      val checkedIndex: Int = itemView.choices.indexOfChild(itemView.choices.findViewById(checkedID))
      
      if(checkedIndex + 1 == answerKey.toInt()) {
        rightOrWrong = "Correct! Next Question."
      } else {
        rightOrWrong = "Incorrect :/ Next Question."
      }

      itemView.result_button.text = rightOrWrong

    }
  }
}
```

And the QuizActivity.kt file

```
class QuizActivity : BaseActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)

        val myAdapter = MyAdapter()

        quiz_list.adapter = myAdapter

//        quiz_list.result_button.setOnClickListener {
//          No idea how to get the children correctly, as this one throws errors
//        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, why do you want to use `RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>` as an adapter for `viewpager2`? There is `FragmentStateAdapter` a built-in class implementation of PagerAdapter that uses a Fragment to manage each page, which is recommended for viewpager2.

Second, you are not inflating the views in `MyViewHolder`, I don't know if you left them intentionally for this post.

You cant access child views like this `quiz_list.result_button.setOnClickListener {}` while using something like RecyclerView, Viewpagger. You can access them in the `ViewHolder` after you inflate them, you can set any listener there aswell

Comment: Point noted, I would consider using the FragmentStateAdapter instead of a RecyclerView Adapter. I am inflating the views in onCreateViewHolder method, just skipped it to keep the code short and to the point.

Comment: I noticed that whatever kind of adapter would be, a click listener can always be set on the child views anyway. The problem part is to swipe it ahead, I guess you pointed me towards that only; that FragmentStateAdapter allows to implement that usecase.

Comment: I noticed that the button ( android:id="@+id/result_button")  is included in the same layout, So when you inflate the *itemView** in VIewHolder you can set OnClicklistener for the button there.

Comment: It seems nearly impossible to me, as I'm fairly new to the android dev game. Can't get to compare the ViewPager component's current item in the onCreateViewHolder. Looking into FragmentStateAdapter now, as suggested by you.